# load json object into ng-option in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-options="priority.level for priority in priority">
```

It return object object, what's wrong? I also tried priority[0].level, it return blank.

```
$scope.priority = [
    {
     "level":"High",
     "index":1
    },

    {
     "level":"Medium",
     "index":2
    },

    {
     "level":"Low",
     "index":3
    }
];
```

Comment: maybe because you named the control variable like the list? Does "p.level for p in priority" work?

Comment: @schlingel YES! omg thx so much. Hw come?!

Comment: @schlingel one question. How to push to sort <li> in <ul>? 

      <li orderBy : selected_priority.index>{{task.name}}</li>

this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all why does your `priority.level for priority in priority` not work?

Counter question, would a loop like that work?

```
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for(var i = 0; list < list.length; i++) {
   list = list[i];

   // do something with list...
}
```

That doesn't work obviously. And you tried to do something similar.

To your sort question: You need to sort the list before you use the elements.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="selected in priority | orderBy:'index'">{{selected.level}}</li>
</ul>
```